# Why does this code for initializing a list of lists apparently link the lists together?

Tags: python, list

I intend to initialize a list of list with length of n.

```
x = [[]] * n
```

However, this somehow links the lists together.

```
>>> x = [[]] * 3
>>> x[1].append(0)
>>> x
[[0], [0], [0]]
```

I expect to have something like:

```
[[], [0], []]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Both questions reference the same code construct: `x = [ [ ] ] * n` followed by `x[ n ].append( y )` and show the same confusion over the behavior `x[ n ] == y` for all values of n.  It could not more clearly be a duplicate.  And yet search engine sent me here first.  ;)

Comment: This question is about how to initialize a list of independent lists. The other question is about why the ```[ [ ] ] * n``` results in "linked" new list behavior. The answers are different, and for those seeking how to do what they want, this is the right question/answer. This is not a duplicate at all, @Loveandpeace-JoeCodeswell is right.

Comment: Note: this was reopened and closed solely for the purposes of fixing the old closure. Do not take my closure as an endorsement of the closure itself.

Answer (score 395, accepted):

The problem is that they're all the same exact list in memory. When you use the `[x]*n` syntax, what you get is a list of `n` many `x` objects, but they're all references to the same object. They're not distinct instances, rather, just `n` references to the same instance.

To make a list of 3 different lists, do this:

```
x = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

This gives you 3 separate instances of `[]`, which is what you want

`[[]]*n` is similar to

```
l = []
x = []
for i in range(n):
    x.append(l)
```

While `[[] for i in range(3)]` is similar to:

```
x = []
for i in range(n):
    x.append([])   # appending a new list!
```

---

```
In [20]: x = [[]] * 4

In [21]: [id(i) for i in x]
Out[21]: [164363948, 164363948, 164363948, 164363948] # same id()'s for each list,i.e same object


In [22]: x=[[] for i in range(4)]

In [23]: [id(i) for i in x]
Out[23]: [164382060, 164364140, 164363628, 164381292] #different id(), i.e unique objects this time
```

Comment: I've just been struggling with the same problem and my brain was nearly blown away. Your answer really helped me.

Comment: Use `_` instead `i` for passing "'i' value is not used" inspection.

Comment: Spent hours debugging a script for which this behaviour was the root cause - thanks very much for the excellent answer.

Comment: Hi, if I want to initialize a list of lists that has no predetermined length, how can I do that without *n making all the elements the same...?

Comment: Create a list containing one empty list. Keep appending an empty list to the outer list as required

Comment: Do you think this is a bug of python or it is designed so

Comment: This behavior has been known for a very long time. If it were a bug, I'd imagine it would have been squashed by now. I therefore believe that this is intentional

Comment: This is not a bug, it is simply consistent behaviour combined with the perils of mutability. The inner `[]` is evaluated only once when writing `[[]]*n` while it is evaluated `n` times when writing `[[] for _ in range(n)]`. If you write `[1]*3` the compiler constructs a list with the object `1`, and then concatenates three copies of that list. Because `1` is immutable nothing special happens when you edit one of the items in the resulting list. However, if you replace `1` with a list you first create a list with a reference to that list, and then concatenate n copies of that list.