# How do I create a list of independent sets in python?

Tags: python

I have a list that needs to contain a variable number of independent sets. 
When I run the following piece of code, I want to add the string "testing" to only the first set.

```
numberOfSets = 3    
test = [set()]*numberOfSets
test[0].add("testing")
print test
```

However, when I print `test`, it shows three identical sets that all contain testing. How can I set up my list so I can separately access each set?

Comment: Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12791510/198633) to [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12791501/198633)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes, that is what I was asking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `[set()]*3`, you create three sets that reference the same object, thus when you change one value, the others change. Use a list comprehension here instead:

```
>>> numberOfSets = 3   
>>> test = [set() for _ in xrange(numberOfSets)]
>>> test[0].add("testing")
>>> print test
[set(['testing']), set([]), set([])]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will accept in 10 minutes

Comment: Since we know the OP is using Python 2.7, you may want to update this answer to use `xrange`; it's more appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
test = [set() for _ in xrange(numberOfSets)]  # use 'range' in Python 3.x
```

`[set()]*x` creates a list with `x` of the *same* set instance, whereas the comprehension above creates a new, independent set on each iteration, as desired.

In general, you should be very cautious whenever you multiply lists whose elements are mutable.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'm using Python 2.7 so I will accept the other answer.

Comment: Just curious, why should I be careful multiplying lists whose elements are mutable?

Comment: @fdsa `xrange` is better for 2.7, as shown above. I meant you should use `range` in 3.x.

Comment: @fdsa `xrange()` creates an iterator, while `range()` just creates the list. If you're interested for performance in 2.7, then `xrange` is the way to go. However, in Python 3, `xrange()` was removed, and `range` took on the same capabilities as `xrange` did in 2.7

Comment: You want to be careful for exactly the reason you describe: mutating one element of the multiplied list can effect other elements. With immutable list elements, you never need to worry about this.