# How to create a number of empty nested lists in python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to have a variable that is a nested list of a number of empty lists that I can fill in later. Something that looks like:

```
my_variable=[[], [], [], []]
```

However, I do not know beforehand how many lists I will need, only at the creation step, therefore I need a variable `a` to determine it. 
I thought about simple `my_variable=[[]]*a`, but that creates copies of lists and it is not what I want to have.

I could do:

```
my_variable=[]  
for x in range(a):
   my_variable.append([])
```

but I'm looking for a more elegant solution (preferably one-liner). Is there any?

Comment: I think you need to rethink this, This seems like it could be better to use a dictionary for your needs. Consult [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `my_variable=[[] for _ in xrange(a)]`

Comment: +1 to Inbar Rose's comment... i had to convert some perl code (where you can instantiate any index at any time, which python doesn't allow.. x = [], x[4] = 1 works in perl, throws an error in python). however, just make x a dictionary, and it will work the same way: x = {}, x[4] = 1 now works just fine. you will have to sort the keys, and they won't be monotonic though (i.e. you could have indexes like [0,3,4,7]).

Comment: Something you may want instead: [defaultdict(list)](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict).

Comment: This is a duplicate

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lst = [[] for _ in xrange(a)]
```

See below:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> lst = [[] for _ in xrange(a)]
>>> lst
[[], [], []]
>>> a = 10
>>> lst = [[] for _ in xrange(a)]
>>> lst
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> # This is to prove that each of the lists in lst is unique
>>> lst[0].append(1)
>>> lst
[[1], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>>
```

Note however that the above is for Python 2.x.  On Python 3.x., since `xrange` was removed, you will want this:

```
lst = [[] for _ in range(a)]
```

Comment: I mast have had a black-out, that I haven't thought about list comprehension before. :) However, I'm wondering why `xrange` on Python 2.x is better than `range`? They both work the same, aren't they?

Comment: @AndyS.c. - Not actually.  In Python 2.x, `xrange` (which returns an xrange iterator) is faster than `range` (which returns a list).  In Python 3.x. however, `range` was made to do what `xrange` does and so `xrange ` was removed.  Here is a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range

Answer (score 14):

```
>>>[[] for x in range(10)] #To make a list of n different lists, do this:
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Edit :-

```
[[]]*10
```

This will give you the same result like above but the list are not distinct instances,they are just n references to the same instance.

Comment: It would be helpful to demonstrate how this differs from `[[]]*10`

Comment: ya that is good.i missed it.

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget it differs like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791501/python-initializing-a-list-of-lists