# Creating a multidimensional list and appending element[]

Tags: python, python-2.7

I only want to append [1] to the first list element of the main list, tree, but [1] gets appended to each list element.

```
tree = [[]] * 5
tree[0].append([1])
print tree

>>>[[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]]
```

What I want:

```
>>>[[[1]],[],[],[],[]]
```

Comment: see [the several questions linked to here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249201/how-to-create-a-number-of-empty-nested-lists-in-python#comment28494052_19249201) and the question on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that multiplying with * creates references of the same element. I should use:

```
tree = [[] for i in xrange(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you create the list (`tree = [[]] * 5`) is the problem. All the 5 lists inside the list are identical objects which you can see when using the method `id()`:

```
>>> tree = [[]] * 5
>>> id(tree[0])
139859652123032
>>> id(tree[1])
139859652123032
```

The solution would be:

```
>>> tree = [[], [], [], [], []]
>>> tree[0].append([1])
>>> tree
[[[1]], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for statement to iterate and add each branch

```
tree = [[] for i in xrange(5)]   
    # xrange() and range() will have the same result, but the former is a cheaper iterator
```

Finally, append '[1]' to the first list

```
tree[0].append([1])
```

Comment: You should not really use a list comp for side effects, why would you not just tree = `[[] for i in xrange(4)]`

Comment: Personal preference I suppose. *added to my answer.