# Creating a list of lists Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

I'm used to C programming where if you wanted to allocate space 2d array you just declare it as

int a[20][20];

I'm not too used to Python programming yet (I'm still in the C mindstate)

I want to declare a list of lists in this section of code and initalize each element to none.

```
class World:
    def __init__(self):
        grid = [[none]*20]*20
```

For some reason it doesn't look right to me. Can someone help me out?

Comment: While valid code (well, by `none`, I assume you mean `None`), I seriously doubt that that's what you want. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12791510/198633)

Comment: also you should probably use `self.grid`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grid = [[None]*20]*20 will give you a list of 20 sublists, each of which contains 20`None`s. However, all the sublists will be references to the same list in memory, so changing one will affect them all.

You're better off doing something like this:

```
grid = [[None for _ in xrange(20)] for __ in xrange(20)]
```

This will give you 20 distinct sublists, each of which contains 20 `None`s

[**Further reading**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791510/198633)