# Is there a shorter way to assign these variables?

Tags: python, variables

Say my program needs to declare the following variables when it starts:

```
Pos_List  = []
Room_List = []
Type_List = []
Spec_List = []
Sub_List  = []
Rtr_List  = []
IPa_List  = []
MAC_List  = []
```

Currently to do this, I have exactly as shown above. My question is, is there a shorter way to do this, or even a way to do this all on one line? There are a couple of times in my program that this sort of thing occurs, and it takes up a lot of space. Any Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: obligatory link: [keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
Pos_List, Room_List, Type_List, Spec_List, Sub_List, Rtr_List, IPa_List, MAC_List = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

I would recommend you to follow [Python naming conventions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions): `pos_list` instead of `Pos_List`

Comment: Yes that will work. I though [] * 8 would too, but it only returns a single empty list.

Comment: Thanks, cleans things up nicely. Just to clarify, since I'm new to python, is the naming convention issue just regarding the use of capital letters?

Comment: The most important: Class names like `CapWords`. Variables and methods like `variable_name` or `method_name()`, for further information read the link I posted.

Comment: @tayfun: What you wanted to do is `[[]] * 8`, which returns a list of 8 empty lists. Except that it's actually returning a list of the _same_ empty list 8 times, which is probably not what you're looking for. In which case: `[[] for _ in range(8)]`.

Comment: While it may not be the "best" way of doing what I want, I'm going to go with the original way Christian suggested, as I understand it the most, and I forsee less editing required in the rest of the program. Thanks to everyone who provided suggestions

Comment: @abarnert: thanks for the clarification. It is "safe" to use such multiplication on immutable types but for lists it will have reference to the same one. For example: ```[0] * 8``` will be OK but ```[[]] * 8``` is not.

Comment: @tayfun: Well, it's "safe" to use `[[]] * 8` when you actually want 8 references to the same list. (See the `grouper` recipe in `itertools` for a simple example of something similar, creating a list of references to the same iterator.) It's just important to know which you're doing when you have mutable objects, while with immutable objects it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you should be using a more sensible data structure like

```
lists = {"Pos": [], "Room": [], "Type": [],...}
```

instead of all these very similar names.

Comment: An alternative might be `collections.defaultdict(list)` and the OP doesn't worry about pre-initialising the types... They just use them...

Comment: Or `lists = {name: [] for name in ("Pos", "Room", "Type")}`, instead of repeating the `[]` over and over.

Answer (score 1):

[The list multiplication syntax is not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12791501/198633). Try this instead:

```
Pos_List, Room_List, Type_List, Spec_List, Sub_List, Rtr_List, IPa_List, MAC_List = [[]for _ in range(8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

And little bit crazy addition for all those answers

```
for name in "Pos Room Type Spec Sub Rtr IPa MAC".split():
    globals()[name+"_List"] = []
```