# A sequence of empty lists of length n in Python?

Tags: python, list, sequence

In python `[]*2`, gives `[]`

What is the simplest way to get `[[],[]]` instead?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791501/python-initializing-a-list-of-lists

Comment: cheers mods, touche` , but the problem is that the dupe's title is not precise enough to have search for it efficiently - i'll edit theirs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want:

```
[[] for _ in range(n)]
```

Unlike `[[]] * n`, this will give you **unique** inner lists (appending to *one* doesn't append to them *all*).  e.g.:

```
>>> x = [[] for _ in range(n)]
>>> x[0].append(1) 
>>> x
[[1], [], []]
```

compared to:

```
>>> x = [[]] * 3
>>> x[0].append(1)
>>> x
[[1], [1], [1]]
```

Note that this latter idiom (`[[]] * n`) is a *very* common mistake that crops up around here in different contexts pretty frequently.

Answer (score 4):

Use comprehension:

```
[[] for _ in range(2)]
```

Answer (score -3):

That's because (e.g.) `[1]*3` gives `[1,1,1]`, i.e., a sequence containing the contents of the list.

Hence you want to duplicate the value `[]`:

```
a = [[]]*2
```

giving

```
[[], []]
```

Because of the way the `*` operator works, this gives copies of the *same* list. Hence, if you try to modify either of those inner empty lists, it effects both of them. (Since they're empty, just about the only thing you can do is append to them; i.e., `a[0].append(1)` gives `[[1],[1]]`.) This is possibly, but unlikely, what you want.

Comment: Now try `a = [[]]*2; a[0].append(1); print a`

Comment: For the same reason we downvoted all the other deleted answers.

Comment: Your solution does not create unique lists. Both inner lists refer to the same object hence if you perform any in-place operation on one the others get affected as well

Comment: Yes, this is *probably* not what the OP wants. But it was not well specified...