# How to add element to a 2d array Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I have a matrix

```
matrix = [[0.0] * 4] * 4
```

it looks like:

```
0    0    0   0
0    0    0   0
0    0    0   0
0    0    0   0
```

I'm trying to add an element to the second row, third column so that the matrix looks like this:

```
0    0    0   0
0    0    3   0
0    0    0   0
0    0    0   0
```

When I do

```
matrix[1][2] = 3
```

it gives:

```
0    0    3   0
0    0    3   0
0    0    3   0
0    0    3   0
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: ... and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12791501/198633)

Comment: There are literally hundreds of dups of this question (in fact, this is the third one today!), so I'm not sure how well the particular one I chose answers your question. If it's not clear, follow the Linked and Related questions from there until you find one that does.

Comment: Also, this is covered [in the official Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list).

Comment: @abarnert thanks, the one in the official Python FAQ answered my question.