# How to shuffle a list 6 times?

Tags: python, list, random

I want to shuffle a list 6 times but I keep getting the same result for all the 6 occasions. Can somebody help me find where the fault is?

Here is the code I used

```
import random
lis1=[0,1,2,3]
lis2=[]
for i in range(6):
    random.shuffle(lis1)
    lis2.append(lis1)
print lis2
```

And here is a sample result I got

```
[[1,3,2,0],[1,3,2,0],[1,3,2,0],[1,3,2,0],[1,3,2,0],[1,3,2,0]]
```

If I get jumbled lists, how can I sort them in ascending order? As in,I want to get this -

```
[[0,1,2,3],[2,3,1,0],[2,1,3,0],[1,0,3,2]]
```

into this-

```
[[0,1,2,3],[1,0,3,2],[2,1,3,0],[2,3,1,0]]
```

Comment: You are shuffling and appending the **same** list 6 times.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python initializing a list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791501/python-initializing-a-list-of-lists) (see the answer, the `*` syntax is different but the result/issue is the same)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your code repeatedly inserts a `lis1` reference into `lis2`. Since `lis1` stays the same all this time, all of `lis2` elements end up pointing to the same object. To fix this, you need to change the `append()` line to make a copy of the list each time:

```
lis2.append(lis1[:])
```

Now, to sort the result simply call `sort()` after the loop:

```
lis2.sort()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something simpler:

```
>>> first = [0,1,2,3]
>>> jumbled = [random.sample(first, len(first)) for i in range(6)]
>>> ordered = sorted(jumbled)
>>> jumbled
[[0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2, 1]]
>>> ordered
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1, 3], [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 3, 2, 1], [0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Store copy of `lis1` not actual `lis1`
   do this:

```
lis2.append(lis1[:])
```

Then code will be:

```
import random
lis1=[0,1,2,3]
lis2=[]
for i in range(6):
    random.shuffle(lis1)
    lis2.append(lis1[:])

print lis2
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 1, 0], [0, 3, 2, 1], [3, 0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0, 3], [3, 0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
lis1=[0,1,2,3]
lis2=[]
for i in range(6):
    r = random.randint(0,len(lis1))
    #print(r)
    lis2.append(lis1[r:]+lis1[:r])
print(lis2)
print(sorted(lis2))
```

Comment: This can only produce a small subset of permutations.

Comment: Yeah I agree it rotates the list not shuffle. I did't notice that while posting. Thanks for mentioning