# a bug in nested lists assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to change one cell in one nested list, and get the cell changed in all the nested lists.

example:

```
>>> temp_list = [['a']*2]*3
>>> temp_list
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
>>> temp_list[2][0] = 'b'
>>> temp_list
[['b', 'a'], ['b', 'a'], ['b', 'a']]
>>>
```

Comment: This is because ['a']*2] make list of [address of 'a', address 'a'] rather than [data 'a', data 'a']. When you did assignment, then value of that address got updated instead of data.

Comment: It is not a bug. List is a mutable sequence type.

Check this url: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list

Comment: Another interesting link to understand what is going on: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Lists#List_creation_shortcuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know, it sounds wrong, but ...

> This is not a bug, it's a feature.

```
>>> [id(x) for x in temp_list]
[4473545216, 4473545216, 4473545216]
```

As you can see, they all share the same reference. Therefore, you need to create a copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.7 I get the same behavior. Each instance that results from the * expansion refers to the same variable.

```
>>> temp_list = [['a']*2]*3
>>> temp_list
[['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
>>> temp_list[2][0] = 'b'
>>> temp_list
[['b', 'a'], ['b', 'a'], ['b', 'a']]
>>> temp_list[1][0] = 'c'
>>> temp_list
[['c', 'a'], ['c', 'a'], ['c', 'a']]
>>> temp_list[1][1] = 'x'
>>> temp_list
[['c', 'x'], ['c', 'x'], ['c', 'x']]
```

See: [Python initializing a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791501/python-initializing-a-list-of-lists)