# Appending of items not as desired outside nested for loop

Tags: python

I would like to write all the permutations of 6 into blocks of 4. When I do the print(template) it actually prints the desired permutation:
[Permutations work fine as seen on the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek9eg.png)

However when I append them to the big_template and print the big_template (which I want to contain a list of all the permutations) all it prints is a list of [6,6,6,6].

[Big_template is not as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhqvI.png)

Here is my code:

```
template = ['' for i in range(4)]
big_template = []
j=0
for i in range(1,7):
    template[j]=i
    for i in range(1,7):
        template[j+1]=i
        for i in range(1,7):
            template[j+2]=i
            for i in range(1,7):
                template[j+3]=i
                print(template)
                big_template.append(template)
print(big_template)
```

My question is what I am doing wrong. Also I would like to extend this procedure to permutations of 6 in any number box. By my method I would have as many for loops as entries into the box. How can this be done using recursion functions?

Cheers.

Comment: You should consider using the [itertools permutation function](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using methods from itertools, such as [permutation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

In your example, each element of `big_template` is the same object, `template`, as you can see using the [is operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is).

```
print(big_template[0] is template)
print(big_template[0] is big_template[1])
```

will both yield `True`. This explains why `big_template` only containts `[6,6,6,6]`, which is the last value taken by `template`.

See [Python initializing a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791501/python-initializing-a-list-of-lists) for example, for more in this topic.

To make your code work as it is, you should call [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html): `big_template.append(template.copy())`.

But you really should use permutation instead.