# Unexpected results using zip to create dict from two lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list that I want to be the keys of a dict. I am trying to initialize all the dict's values to an empty dict using zip, like this:

```
day_list = list(range(1,4))
days = dict(zip(day_list, [{}] * len(day_list)))
```

The `days` dict initially looks like what I want, but the problem appears once I start trying to populate it.

```
for day, day_dict in days.items():
    print('Processing day', day)
    day_dict['input_file'] = 'forecast_day{}.zip'.format(day)
    
print(days)
```

All the values are from the last time through the `for` loop. It seems like the values in my dict are all pointing to the same object, since they all contain the last settings of the loop:

```
    Processing day 1
    Processing day 2
    Processing day 3
    {1: {'input_file': 'forecast_day3.zip'}, 2: {'input_file': 'forecast_day3.zip'}, 3: {'input_file': 'forecast_day3.zip'}}
```

If I create `days` like this (instead of via `zip`), everything works like I'd expect, in that the values can all be set independently:

```
days = {}
for day in day_list:
    days[day] = {}
```

While that solves my problem, it doesn't further my understanding. It also feels less Pythonic than zipping two lists. Any wisdom on understanding why my first attempt didn't work and/or how to do this in a Pythonic way is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python initializing a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791501/python-initializing-a-list-of-lists) In your case it is a list of empty dicts but the situation is essentially the same. In short, you can try `[{} for _ in day_list]`

Comment: Valuable education: [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)

Comment: It looks like the `*` operator was the issue. It created a list of not just the same values, but the same object. So updating any one of them was updating all of them. Creating `days` like this works the way I expected: `days = dict(zip(day_list, [{} for i in range(len(day_list)+1)]))`

Comment: Test for the object's reuse with the `id()` function.