# How would I go about pasting an array over a 2D array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

### The Objective

I need to take an array with data that can be displayed in 2 dimensions, and paste it over any part of a 2D array as if it were an image. This function would be similar to the Python library Pillow's [paste function](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste).

### Example

Say I have a 2D array with a size of 5x5, with a default value of 0.

```
[
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

And I have an average array with the length of 4, which can be assembled into 2x2 form.

```
[0, 1, 
 1, 1]
```

With this, I need a function to, as if these arrays were images, 'paste' the second over the first. With a position (anchored from the top left) of (1,2), it would result in this 2D array.

```
[
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

### My Attempt

Here is my attempt at creating the Python code.

```py
class Indexed:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.array = [[0]*x]*y
        self.dimensions = (x, y)

    def writeImage(self, indexed, x, y, width, height):
        index = 0
        for ArrayY in range(height):
            self.array[ArrayY] = [0]*self.dimensions[0]
            for ArrayX in range(width):
                self.array[1 + ArrayY][x + ArrayX] = indexed[index]
                index+=1
                
Test = Indexed(12,12)
Test.writeImage(
        [
            0,0,7,0,0,7,0,0,
            0,0,7,0,0,7,0,0,
            0,0,7,0,0,7,0,0,
            7,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,
            7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
        ],
        0,0, 8,5
    )
print(Test.array)
```

### The Problem

If you attempt to run the code above, you will see that it outputs this result.

```py
[
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

This is the intended result.

```py
[
 [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

I've tinkered with it a lot and haven't found any answers online for why these arrays work the way they do here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by ***array***? In *NumPy* this can be done via a single (assignment + slicing) statement. Also *writeImage*'s last 2 arguments could (**should**) be inferred from *indexed*.

Comment: @CristiFati writeImage's last two arguments are meant to specify the width and height of the array you are passing in. The input **array** I pass through with the width and height could be a 2D array as well, however with how I receive the data I believe it would be too much of a hassle to paste onto a 2D array using a 2D array. The best way I can describe this process is like pasting one smaller picture (Input array) over a larger one (Indexed.array).

Comment: By *array* I meant it's a list, a tuple an *NumPy* array? Because some already have this functionality built-in. I now see the input array is a *1D* one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791501/why-does-this-code-for-initializing-a-list-of-lists-apparently-link-the-lists-to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialise self.array `[[0]*x]*y`. The [0]*x is only shallow copied (reference only) y times, which means all of the row is basically the same array.

Since it is the same array, it's final value would be the last row, i.e. `7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7`. Thats why the one updated is such value.

Also noted the index is incorrect in the writeImage

```
from pprint import pprint

class Indexed:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.array = [0]*y
        for i in range(y):
            self.array[i] = [0]*x
        self.dimensions = (x, y)

    def writeImage(self, indexed, x, y, width, height):
        for ArrayY in range(height):
            for ArrayX in range(width):
                index = (ArrayY * width) + ArrayX
                self.array[y + ArrayY][x + ArrayX] = indexed[index]
                
Test = Indexed(12,12)
Test.writeImage(
        [
            0,0,7,0,0,7,0,0,
            0,0,7,0,0,7,0,0,
            0,0,7,0,0,7,0,0,
            7,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,
            7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
        ],
        0,0, 8,5
    )
pprint(Test.array)
```